# Why does my form still submit when my javascript function returns false?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Here is my Javascript formvalidator function:

```js
function companyName() {
    var companyName = document.forms["SRinfo"]["companyName"].value;
    if (companyName == ""){
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
}

function companyAdd() {
    var companyAdd1 = document.forms["SRinfo"]["companyAdd1"].value;
    if (companyAdd1 == ""){
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
}

function companyCity() {
    var companyCity = document.forms["SRinfo"]["companyCity"].value;
    if (companyCity == ""){
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
}

function companyZip() {
    var companyZip = document.forms["SRinfo"]["companyZip"].value;
    if (companyZip == ""){
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
}

function enteredByName() {
    var enteredByName = document.forms["SRinfo"]["enteredByName"].value;
    if (enteredByName == ""){
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
}

function dayPhArea() {
    var dayPhArea = document.forms["SRinfo"]["dayPhArea"].value;
    if (dayPhArea == ""){
    return false;
    }
}

function dayPhPre() {
    var dayPhPre = document.forms["SRinfo"]["dayPhPre"].value;
    if (dayPhPre == ""){
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
}

function dayPhSub() {
    var dayPhSub = document.forms["SRinfo"]["dayPhSub"].value;
    if (companyAdd1 == ""){
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
}

function validateForm() {
        if (companyName() && companyAdd() && companyCity() && companyZip() && enteredByName() && dayPhArea() && dayPhPre() && dayPhSub()) {
            return true;        

        } else {
            window.alert("Please make sure that all required fields are completed.");
            document.getElementByID("companyName").className = "reqInvalid";
            companyName.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here are all of my includes, just in case one conflicts with another (I am using jquery for their toggle()):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="formvalidator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="autoTab.js"></script>
<?php 
require_once('mobile_device_detect.php');
include_once('../db/serviceDBconnector.php');
$mobile = mobile_device_detect();

if ($mobile) {
        header("Location: ../mobile/service/index.php");
    if ($_GET['promo']) {
        header("Location: ../mobile/service/index.php?promo=".$_GET['promo']);
    }
}

?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

Here is my form tag with the function returned onSubmit:

```html
<form method="POST" action="index.php" name="SRinfo" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

The validation works perfectly, I tested all fields and I keep getting the appropriate alert, however after the alert the form is submitted into mysql and sent as an email. Here is the code where I submit my POST data.

```php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
// Here I submit to Mysql database and email form submission using php mail()
```

Comment: You should validate the form server-side too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem to me that this line is likely blowing up:

```
companyName.focus();
```

The only definition I see for `companyName` is the function.  You can't call `focus` on a function.

This blows up so the `return false` is never reached.

Comment: Good call, that line was left over from my previous version of the formValidator, which the first version did work but my boss didn't like multiple alert's. When I removed that line it didn't work but then I removed both `document.getElementByID("companyName").className = "reqInvalid";` & `companyName.focus();` and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would comment out all the code in the validation section and simply return false.  If this stops the form from posting then there is an error in the actual code performing the validation.  Add each part one at a time until the error is found.

My guess is the same as James suggests that you are calling focus on the function 'companyName'.  The line above this seems to be trying to get the element from the document with the same name but you are not assigning this to a variable so that you can call focus on it.